# Autocomplete inside a backbone modal dialog overflow hidden not working?

Tags: jquery, css, backbone.js

I am using backbone modal dilaog and inside it using an autocomplete using jquery.backbone.widgets.js. The autocomplete list is supposed to overlay on top on modal dialog and it must overflow without being scrollable. But it is making the modal dialog to scroll. Can you suggest the css changes that can make the functionality like I need.

Comment: Can you add some example code and what you tried to do as well?

Comment: this is the css I used for the autocomplete for the input box inside backbone modal:

                    ul.autocomplete {
 position:absolute;
 background-color:white;
 border:1px solid #999;
 width:100%;
 list-style:none;
 font-size:12px;
 overflow:visible;
 clear:both;}

ul.autocomplete li {
 cursor:pointer;
 margin:0;
 padding:5px;

    }

ul.autocomplete li.selected {
 background-color:#E1EFF9;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.modal { overflow: visible; }
.modal-body { overflow-y: visible; }

This solved my problem.